# White space under grid container when viewing on mobile

Tags: css, css-grid

When I try to view my page on a mobile device specifically Chrome browser (not Firefox) I get white space under the container. Below is the code. It seems to happen when I have wide content in the main element.

http://demo.microcad.ca/web/test/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html { height: 100%; }
        body { min-height: 100%; margin: 0;}
        .container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-rows: 50px;
          grid-template-columns: 250px;
          grid-template-areas: 
               "aside header"
               "aside main";
          height: 100vh;
        }
        aside {
          grid-area: aside;
          background: #2f313a;
        }
        header {
          grid-area: header;
          background: #fff;
        }
        main {
          grid-area: main;
          background: #ebedf3;
        }
    </style>
<head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <aside>aside</aside>
      <header>header</header>
      <main>main
          <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Age</th><th>Height</th><th>Registration</th><th>Logged In</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>t, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi neque orci, auct</td><td>t, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi neque orci, auct</td><td>t, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi neque orci, auct</td><td>t, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi neque orci, auct</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Can't reproduce, Seems to work fine

Comment: Did you view it on a mobile device? Scroll to the very bottom of the page and you will see lots of white space

Answer (score 0):

It's a table related issue, table being a table it has to stay in view and keep it's aspect ratio, so a simple solution is to make it's container scroll.

```
main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #ebedf3;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Or you can remove this line so the viewport isn't calculated based on the screen size.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**Not recommended.**

Comment: I feel like this is more of a workaround than an actual solution to the problem, I appreciate your idea.